# Seeking for faster $.(':data(key)')

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I'm writing an extension to jQuery that adds data to DOM elements using

```
el.data('lalala', my_data);
```

and then uses that data to upload elements dynamically.

Each time I get new data from the server I need to update all elements having

```
el.data('lalala') != null;
```

To get all needed elements I use an extension by [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/):

```
$(':data(lalala)').each(...);
```

Everything was great until I came to the situation where I need to run that code 50 times - it is **very slow**! It takes about 8 seconds to execute on my page with 3640 DOM elements

```
var x, t = (new Date).getTime();
for (n=0; n < 50; n++) {
  jQuery(':data(lalala)').each(function() {
    x++;
  });
};
console.log(((new Date).getTime()-t)/1000);
```

Since I don't need RegExp as parameter of `:data` selector I've tried to replace this by

```
var x, t = (new Date).getTime();
for (n=0; n < 50; n++) {
  jQuery('*').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('lalala'))
      x++;
  });
};
console.log(((new Date).getTime()-t)/1000);
```

This code is faster (5 sec), but I want get more.

**Q** Are there any faster way to get all elements with this data key?

In fact, I can keep an array with all elements I need, since I execute `.data('key')` in my module. Checking 100 elements having the desired `.data('lalala')` is better then checking 3640 :)

So the solution would be like

```
for (i in elements) {
  el = elements[i];
  ....
```

But sometimes elements are removed from the page (using jQuery `.remove()`). Both solutions described above [`$(':data(lalala)')` solution and `if ($(this).data('lalala'))`] will skip removed items (as I need), while the solution with array will still point to removed element (in fact, the element would not be really deleted - it will only be deleted from the DOM tree - because my array will still have a reference).

I found that `.remove()` also removes data from the node, so my solution will change into

```
var toRemove = [];

for (vari in elements) {
  var el = elements[i];
  if ($(el).data('lalala'))
    ....
  else
    toRemove.push(i);
};

for (var ii in toRemove)
  elements.splice(toRemove[ii], 1); // remove element from array
```

This solution is 100 times faster!

**Q** Will the garbage collector release memory taken by DOM elements when deleted from that array?

Remember, elements have been referenced by DOM tree, we made a new reference in our array, then removed with `.remove()` and then removed from the array.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have asked 2-3 questions in this. Which is the question you really want the answer to?

Comment: Both Q. The first one is more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any faster way to get all elements with this data key?

Sure!, loop over the data store directly instead of via the element, for example if you wanted a count:

```
var x=0;
for(var key in $.cache) { 
  if(typeof $.cache[key]["lalala"] != "undefined") x++; 
}
```

This will be nearly instant, since elements only have an entry in `$.cache` if they have data and/or events, and there's **no** DOM traversal happening.

For the other piece, yes this will skip removed elements, since their cache is cleaned up as well, provided you don't remove them via `.innerHTML` directly.

Comment: ... or you don't remove them with other native DOM methods?

Comment: Wow! this is that I was looking for - the place where these data are really stored.

Comment: Wait, and how to retrive the object itself - who is the owner of a particular cached object? I've to loop over DOM to find it?

Comment: @PoltoS - When you find the one you want, it's `$('['+$.expando+'='+key+']')` to get the element it goes with...if you know it's a `<div>`, etc, add that to the selector to make it much faster.

Comment: @Nick Craver - $('['+$.expando+'='+key+']') is empty.

Comment: @PoltoS - you're using this inside the for loop, when `key` is set?

Comment: @Nick Craver - I've tried it in console with correct key. This selector $('['+$.expando+']') also returns empty set. And it is correct - I've no element in DOM with attribute named jQuery123456543212.

Comment: @PoltoS - You won't *see* the attribute, but it's there, it's what jQuery adds for the key in the data collection, instead of a direct reference which IE won't cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Since V1.4.3 jQuery supports the HTML5-data-attribute.
This means: if you set an HTML-attribute `data-lalala` you can also access these attribute using `element.data('lalala')` . This should be much faster, because you an use the
native attribute-selector `$('*[data-lalala]')` instead of some workarounds.

So you have to use:

```
el.attr('data-lalala', my_data);
```

instead of

```
el.data('lalala', my_data);
```

Note: As those [data-attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) only allow strings, you'll need to store objects as a stringified JSON there, if you need to work with objects.

Comment: I need to associate a function with a DOM element, so this solution is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, if the name of the function as string is not sufficient, it may be complicated.